# How to use Array2XML in Laravel 5

Tags: php, xml, laravel

So i have come accross this library `Array2XML` in php and i have just started using laravel, how can i reference that class in my laravel scripts.

Currently i'm getting this error:

```
Class 'afrosoft\Http\Controllers\Array2XML' not found
```

Comment: I would recommend learning to work with XML properly rather than convert it.  SimpleXML is easy to get most XML data (hence name).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code i guess you have forgot to add this package to your Service Container.
Read the readme markdown file of this package and the "how to Install". I think you've missed something

Where did you get the package from?

Answer (score 0):

I released some xml packages designed to work well with Laravel 5. It sounds like you might be interested in painless xml integration with your app. You can find them here:

- [Collection Xml](https://github.com/mtownsend5512/collection-xml)
- [Request Xml](https://github.com/mtownsend5512/request-xml)
- [Response Xml](https://github.com/mtownsend5512/response-xml)
- [Xml To Array](https://github.com/mtownsend5512/xml-to-array)